# Can I tell how an IP address is hitting my website?

Tags: wordpress, ip, bandwidth

My website's bandwidth usage has increased hugely in the last few months, the odd thing is, it's from my own IP address. I've had 16,000 hits in one month from my own IP address. I have no idea why.

Is it possible to monitor why this is happening?
For additional info, it's a new wordpress site with good security measures, including server side.

Are there any simple reasons this could be happening that I can monitor?

Comment: Hits from cache plugins like [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) will come from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

**You can install the following two plugins:**
[All In One WP Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/)
[WP Cerber](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cerber/)